go from last lazarus stringgrid row to first row
I wrote a short routine that jumps from last row of a string to first row.
Code looks fine to me, but when I run the program, it goes to
second row.  The code is below:
rn:=StringGrid35.row;
if rn=23 then StringGrid35.row:=0;
rn is row number, the stringgrid has 24 rows.
I tried stringgrid.row:=1; too, but that din't work
since row count starts at 0 not 1.
I was expecting for the cursor to go from row 23 to row 0,
but went to row 1 (which is second row).
